# SFTP folder access issue with perl program

Tags: perl

I have designed a program for retreiving files from a remote sftp folder, and it was working fine.

And now I am having a weird issue with this program. Please find below the code fragment with which I am having this issue:

```
    my @ls = $sftp->ls("$config->[$i]->{'SOURCE'}") or do {
        $logger->error("Could not retrieve directory listing, exiting from    processing");
        next;
    };
```

**or** statement for $sftp->ls is being executed, which is expcted only when $sftp->ls fails. But I don't have any issue while accessing it manually. Status Code which I have received after $sftp->ls statement is **0**, which means Successful.

I am not sure why it is still redirected to the **or** fragment, please advise. Also there is no issues when the remote folder is not empty.

SFTP used:

```
    use Net::SFTP::Foreign::Compat ':supplant';
```

Answer (score 2):

Your statement `my @ls = ... or ...` checks the result of the `=` operator. Because its LHS is an array, this is list assignment. List assignment in scalar context returns the number of elements on the RHS. In other words, if a non-empty list was returned, everything is OK; an empty list is treated as an error.

You didn't tell us what `$sftp` is. I'm going to assume it's a [Net::SFTP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP) object.

According to the documentation, [`$sftp->ls`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP#sftp-ls-remote-subref) returns a list of directory entries. Therefore your code treats an empty directory as an error. You didn't say this explicitly either, but you did say "*there is no issues when the remote folder is not empty*", implying there's a problem with empty directories.

The issue (as far as I can see) is with your code. It does exactly what you told it to.

---

Update: I've looked at the source code. This is not documented, but you can check for errors separately by calling the method in scalar context:

```
my @ls = do {
    my $ls_ref = $sftp->ls($config->[$i]{SOURCE}) or do {
        $logger->error("Could not retrieve directory listing, exiting from    processing");
        next;
    };
    @$ls_ref
};
```

In scalar context, `ls` returns either a reference to an array of results or `undef` on failure.

Comment: I appreciate your support. I have used Net::SFTP::Foreign::Compat ':supplant';

Comment: `Net::SFTP::Foreign::Compat` doesn't support the undocumented "`ls` in scalar context" thing. You'd have to [check `error` manually](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign#Error-handling).